# Parsing XML Data (2,2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio, rest

I've got a unique problem when I attempt to deserialize XML.

The method is as follows:

```
XmlSerializer serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(APIFile));
using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
     using(XmlReader reader= XmlReader.Create(stream))
     {
          APIFile model = serialize.Deserialize(reader) as APIFile;
          Console.WriteLine(model.lSubmission.Select(m => m.Id));
     }
```

So when the code hits the `model` I receive an error stating:

- `xmlns="> Was not expected.`
- `There is an error in XML document (2,2).`

The model built was populated through Visual Studio *Edit -- Past Special -- XML Class*.

I've tampered with the following line:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
```

I've modified the line:

- Namespace
- xmlns
- Removed the line.
- Changed from a Root Attribute

But the error persist and I'm not entirely sure why.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CanvasResult>
     <TotalPages>8</TotalPages>
     <CurrentPage>1</CurrentPage>
     <Submissions>
          <Submission Id="5840790">
               <Form Id="718013">
                    <Name>Proof of Delivery</Name>
                    <Status>retired</Status>
                    <Version>6</Version>
               </Form>
```

---

That is the first little bit of the XML, after that is some more minor content / section which will build out a little further.  *My document doesn't have a xmlns anywhere in the file, is it possible the Reader or XmlSerializer are adding it?*

Comment: You need to show XML which is likely not XML at all.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The model generated is from an third party XML Rest API; if I add the contents of that file it is quite large. Is it needed?

Comment: While I can't speak for the others, I'm mainly interested in the first few lines of the file.  The code seems to error out at the beginning of the XML document, so I'm inclined to believe that the issue is there.

Comment: Does the text `xmlns=">` (from the error) appear anywhere in the document?

Comment: @Greg thanks for adding XML... but it looks like it is different from one you are getting error on (there is no "xmlns" on second line...)

Comment: Sadly though, it isn't apart of my document period.  Which is why I'm confused as why it is present. It does pass `CanDeserialize` though.

Comment: Remove serialization from the picture and simply store/copy result to another XML. May clarify things (no idea what is going on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to isolate the issue to a couple of items:

- The data model wasn't handling all of the content that was inserted.
- The third party API was passing `&` in the XML, which also caused an error.

I wrote a simple validation method that ran through the file to validate the XML and fix any malformed tags or symbols.

The code that worked that finally deserialized the values is:

```
    public static void ParseToModel(string file)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        XmlSerializer serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CanvasResult));
        using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using(XmlReader reader= XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                CanvasResult model = serialize.Deserialize(reader) as CanvasResult;
                ParseToDatabase(model);
            }
    }
```

The method is called, which will take the file parameter then correlate the content to the data model.  At the end it calls a separate method called `ParseToDatabase` which breaks the content down and placed into the proper column within the database.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way i found of dealing with xml is to use XDocuments / XElements ...

```
using(var reader = StreamReader(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open)))
{
   var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
   var xml = new XElement(data);
   //TODO: query xml with linq or whatever
}
```

Works with whole docs and fragments

Comment: Was trying to automate to a model, to make it cleaner but if I can't I may have to go that route.

Comment: you saying this dom represents the data for a type? so you need to deserialise in to some object?

Comment: 1- What is the use of `serialize` 2- Your *using* stmt should not end with `;` 3- no XElement constructor taking *stream* as parameter. This can be a comment too like the other answer.